# Windows Server 2003 force RDP client to be RDP 6

Tags: windows-server-2003, security, rdp

Hi I was wondering whether it is possible to configure Windows Server 2003 to require that the RDP client that connects to it is version 6 or above, as I believe with version 6 you are able to have better security.

I think it is possible to do something similar on Windows 7, so I was wondering if it could be done on Server 2003.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking if 2003 supports NLA (Network Level Authentication) the answer is no.  The best you can do is crank up the encyption settings.

If you really wanted more secuity you could also set up a 2008 machine with the TS gateway service installed.  Force your connections through that.